# Serialization Proxy With Custom Form?

Tags: java, file, serialization, file-io

If I'm using the serialization proxy pattern, should I provide a custom `writeObject` method for the containing class, or just the proxy? Should I even use a custom form for the proxy? I've read the chapter from Effective Java about Serialization, but it wasn't clear about custom forms and the proxy pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the serialization proxy pattern, instances of the original class are never serialized using the "normal" serialization mechanism. So if the original class were to have a `writeObject` implementation, it would never get called.

Although you won't need a `writeObject` method, you should probably write a `readObject` method in your original class. Older serialized instances of your class may be out there, if they were serialized before you introduced proxying. Or, someone could have forged a byte stream that *looks like* a conventional serialized form of your original class. Deserializing this would bypass the proxy and possibly create a malformed instance of your original class. To prevent this, throw an exception unconditionally from the `readObject` method of your original class, to prevent any deserialization from bypassing the proxy. (This is mentioned in *Effective Java* but it's important that I felt I should repeat it here.)

As for a custom form of the serial proxy, it's not absolutely necessary. *Effective Java* suggests that the serial proxy class be designed simply and plainly enough that you can use the default serialized form. If this works for you, great, you can just use the default form. But another pattern I've started to see is where a single serialization proxy is used as the proxy for several different serializable classes. In this case the proxy class isn't a nested class, but instead is just a package-private class in the same package. The proxy will probably want to have a custom serialized form so that it can vary the serialized data that's written, depending upon which class it's the proxy for.

The serialization of the new `java.time` classes in the JDK does this, with a single serial proxy for several data classes. See the [Ser.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/time/Ser.java) file to see how this is done. This is a bit more complicated, though, since it uses `Externalizable` interfaces instead of the special serialization methods, and it delegates back to the data classes to do the reading and writing. But you can see the principles at work.

Answer (score 0):

The original class should have a `writeReplace()` method that returns an instance of the proxy class, and the proxy class should have a `readResolve()` method that returns an instance of the original class.

> should I provide a custom writeObject method for the containing class

No.

> or just the proxy?

No.

> Should I even use a custom form for the proxy?

No. Keep the proxy class as simple as possible, i.e. a POJO.